# How can I do side-by-side simulation of Simulink files by using for-loop in MATLAB GUI or is there another way to do it?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, user-interface, simulink

I want to ask how I make the following code functioning for side-by-side simulation of Simulink files, which are saved in 'PATH', by using for-loop in MATLAB GUI or if you know an alternative way to do it. After I started to run the code, nothing happened although no error message has come. Also I hope that some of you get solutions of my problem.

Thank you very much in advance!

```
function nightly_simulation_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to nightly_simulation (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
PATH = 'C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Saved_Models';
files=dir([PATH,'*.slx']);
fileNames={files.name}; 
fileNames=sort(fileNames);
nFiles=numel(fileNames); 
selection = questdlg('Sure to start?',...
    'Confirmation',...
    'Yes','No','Yes');
switch selection
    case 'Yes'
        for i=1:nFiles  
            x = [PATH,fileNames{i}];
            open_system(x);
            sim(x);
        end
    case 'No'
        return
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
x = [PATH,fileNames{i}];
```

with

```
x = fullfile(PATH, fileNames{i});
```

since otherwise a `'\'` is missing in the filename.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my code like this:

```
function nightly_simulation_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to nightly_simulation (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
PATH = 'C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Saved_Models';
files = dir( fullfile(PATH,'*.slx') );   %# list all *.slx files
fileNames = {files.name}';
fileNames=sort(fileNames);
nFiles=numel(fileNames); 
selection = questdlg('Sure to start?',...
    'Confirmation',...
    'Yes','No','Yes');
switch selection
    case 'Yes'
        for i=1:nFiles  
       x = fullfile(PATH, fileNames{i}); 
       open_system(x);
       sim(x);
end
    case 'No'
        return
end
```

Also it worked. Thanks for your advice!